# Handling Ubuntu MAAS RestFul API login

Tags: login, maas, cloud, interface

What would be the best practice for obtaining Ubuntu MAAS API login?

I have some troubles with making the MAAS Restful API automatically obtaining successful login and perform a call. In summary, what I am trying to achieve is to simple call the api (login, call a service and then logout). The problem I am facing is with managing the csrf token and pass it to the next call (first make a GET request to get the csrftoken and sessionid, then make a POST for login and finally make a GET request to the API for example. In this sequence on the GET API call, i am always getting the 403 error message (forbidden). I have observed that the POST request to the /accounts/login/
is actually performing redirection to /MAAS/, which seems to have confused my expected response or so, which is causing the sessionid/csrftoken not to be authenticated.

The only way I have managed to make it working is simple to perform the authentication manually and then to import the sessionid and csrftoken into the GET REST API call. Nevertheless I would like to automate this process and any suggestions would be in a great appreciation.

I am using groovy + wslite in the current setup. Any similar implementation will be in good use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how this would translate in groovy but an example Python code can be found in

- http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~maas-maintainers/maas/trunk/files/head:/src/apiclient/.

In particular:

- http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~maas-maintainers/maas/trunk/view/head:/src/apiclient/maas_client.py.